# How to send email to users using python?

Tags: python

I have to send email to users with their respective servers down.

Code:

```
import smtplib
import time
import re
from string import Template
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#SMTP Credential
user = "username"
password = "pass"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp server')

def get_contacts(filename):

   emails = []
   hostname = []
   ip = []
   with open(filename,'r') as contacts_file:
       for a_contact in contacts_file:
          match = re.match('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$', a_contact.split()[0])
          if match == None:
             emails.append('no_email')
             hostname.append(a_contact.split()[0])
             ip.append(a_contact.split()[1])
           else:
              emails.append(a_contact.split()[0])
              hostname.append(a_contact.split()[1])
              ip.append(a_contact.split()[2])
      return emails, hostname, ip


def main():
   emails, hostname, ip = get_contacts('provider.txt') # read contacts


   # Send email to l2@abc.com if provider's support email address is not available:
   for email, hostname, ip in zip(emails, hostname, ip):
      match = re.match('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$', email)
      if match == None: #If provider does not have support email send email to l2@abc.com
        l2_email = 'l2@abc.com'
        msg = MIMEText("Hello server with main IP %s is currently down." %ip,'html')
        msg['Subject'] = 'Server down %s: %s' % (hostname,ip)
        msg['From'] = 'username@abc.com'
        msg['To'] = l2_email
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user,password)
        server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())


     ##Send email to provider if support email address is found##
      else:
        msg = MIMEText("Hello server with main IP %s is currently down." %ip,'html')
        msg['Subject'] = 'Server down %s: %s' % (hostname,ip)
        msg['From'] = 'username@abc.com'
        msg['To'] = email
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user,password)
        server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
   server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Input:

```
    host1 192.168.100.24
    user1@abc.com  host2 192.168.100.45 host7 192.168.100.40 host3 192.168.100.34 host4 192.168.100.20
    user2@xyz.com  host8 192.168.100.48 host6 192.168.100.43 host10 192.168.100.37 
    host5 192.168.100.24 host9 192.168.100.33
```

I want to send email to user1@abc.com with message like below:

Hello your following servers are down:

host2 192.168.100.45

host7 192.168.100.40

host3 192.168.100.34

host4 192.168.100.20

If the line does not contain email address then to specific email address like l2@abc.com with message like:
Hello your following servers are down:

host1 192.168.100.24

host5 192.168.100.24

host9 192.168.100.33

Currently script is working for only single host. Can any one please help how to implement this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've not explained what your actual problem is. *Why* is it not working? What is it doing now and how does this differ from what you want it to do? Is there an error, if so what error and where?  What have you tried?

Comment: @IrmendeJong, actual problem is only one host information can be included in email for user user1@abc.com instead of all four hosts.

Comment: ...okay, but have you tried to debug anything yourself? I'd start with looking at the result of ``get_contacts`` and see if that contains what you expect so that the ``for`` loop actually loops over multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

In your `get_contacts()` method, you only add one `host` and `ip` per line of contact information processed.

If we reduce your function to something very basic, you'll see what's going on:

```
contact = 'user1@abc.com  host2 192.168.100.45 host7 192.168.100.40 host3 192.168.100.34 host4 192.168.100.20'

# This has an email in it, so we won't bother with the regex check.
print(contact.split()[0])
print(contact.split()[1])
print(contact.split()[2])
```

If you run that code snippet above, you'll get this output:

```
user1@abc.com
host2
192.168.100.45
```

It's because `split()` will break the entire line into a list of elements, so you're only ever going to access at most the first `host` and `ip` combination.

Or more concretely, here's `print(contact.split())` in my Python shell:

```
>> print(contact.split())
['user1@abc.com', 'host2', '192.168.100.45', 'host7', '192.168.100.40', 'host3', '192.168.100.34', 'host4', '192.168.100.20']
```

For your problem, you have many ways of solving it. A basic one is:

- Split the entire string
- Determine if the first element is an email address

  - If email address is found, add that email to a dictionary, then process the rest of the list for the host-ip combinations that will be sent in the email
  - If no email address is found, add a default email to the dictionary, then process the rest of the list for the host-ip combinations that will be sent in the email

---

Here is a modified version of your code which generates a single dictionary with all the hosts bound to whatever email things should be sent to.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_contacts(filename):
    contacts = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename, 'r') as contacts_file:
        for line in contacts_file:
            split_data = line.split()
            if re.match('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$', split_data[0]):
                email = split_data[0]
                # Merge every two elements in the list
                # together to form a host-ip pair
                hosts = [' '.join(i) for i in zip(split_data[1::2], split_data[2::2])]
            else:
                # Some default email here
                email = 'l2@abc.com'
                hosts = [' '.join(i) for i in zip(split_data[0::2], split_data[1::2])]


            contacts[email].extend(hosts)
    return contacts
```

Run this against your data, and your data will look like this:

```
{'l2@abc.com': ['host1 192.168.100.24',
              'host5 192.168.100.24',
              'host9 192.168.100.33'],
 'user1@abc.com': ['host2 192.168.100.45',
              'host7 192.168.100.40',
              'host3 192.168.100.34',
              'host4 192.168.100.20'],
 'user2@xyz.com': ['host8 192.168.100.48',
              'host6 192.168.100.43',
              'host10 192.168.100.37']})
```

Then you just iterate over the structure and send emails as needed:

```
for email, hosts in get_contacts('provider.txt'):
    # ... do what you need to do with the email address
    # and list of hosts
```

Notice some things I've done, and some stuff that I've noticed in your code:

- You kept calling `split()` on the same line of text every time you wanted to do a comparison in your `get_contacts` method. This is unnecessary - split it once and assign to a variable if you're going to keep using it.
- You don't create a body for your email in your code that sends emails.
- Your email regex is probably excessive, since you can't actually guarantee it's a real email. You just want to know that what you're parsing is in an email-like format, so something like `[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+` would probably be just as effective.

Comment: thank you so much for your nice explanation. It really worked fine.

Comment: how can I return if line contains multiple email address one for sender and one for receiver. Like below: user1@abc.com  user2@abc.com host2 192.168.100.45 host7 192.168.100.40 host3 192.168.100.34 host4 192.168.100.20